# mg_wakeup_server_ex ( ) callback not getting called while using mongoose 5.4

Tags: c++, c, callback, mongoose-web-server

I am working with mongoose 5.4
Below are the lines of code

```
char* eventToOCC = NULL;

static int websocket_data_push(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev)
{
    if ((ev == MG_POLL) && (NULL != conn->uri) && (NULL != eventToOCC))
    {
        if (strcmp(conn->uri, "/web") == 0 && conn->is_websocket) {
            mg_websocket_printf(conn, WEBSOCKET_OPCODE_TEXT, "%s",
                                eventToOCC);
        }
    }
    return MG_FALSE;
}


void SampleClass::sendEventsToClinet(char* evString)
{
    if(evString != NULL)
    {
        eventToOCC = evString;
        printf("EVENT SENT is ---%s---\n",evString);
        mg_wakeup_server_ex(mgserver, websocket_data_push, "%lu %s",
                            (unsigned long) time(NULL), (const char *) evString);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connection Pointer is NULL\n");
    }
    return ;
}
```

Here, the callback is not getting called whenever mg_wakeup_server_ex() is invoked. 
I don't suspect c++ method calling a C Method because it works in few cases.
Only at certain places, the websocket_data_push () callback doesnt get called.
Could you please help !!!

Comment: What "C method"? How do you know the callback is not being called?

Comment: I have certain prints in websocket_data_push() function. This is a C function which does not belong to class SampleClass. These prints are not getting printed. The only print i see is "EVENT SENT is --**". and not the one in websocket_data_push()

Comment: Just to clarify, if the function is not in a C source file or marked `extern "C"` then the function is not a C function. If it's in the global scope it's a global static C++ function, if it's in a class it's a C++ static member function.

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that the event which calls the callback really happens? You should also try to run in a debugger, and set a breakpoint on `websocket_data_push` to see if it stops there or not.

Comment: yes i am pretty sure that the callback gets called because it works 2/3 times. Its not working in some use cases only. I suspect its totally a issue related to mongoose, if I am sending proper return values. Thats why wanted to know the possibilities when callback doesnt get called

Comment: I just got the core of the problem To Be specific,
the recv() that is called from ns_server_wakeup_ex () is not returning. and blocked.
Could you please help ?

Comment: Network sockets are by default blocking. If you call e.g. `recv` when there's nothing to receive, then the `recv` function will block and not return until there is something to receive. I have no knowledge of how Mongoose works or its API, but maybe that's the way it's supposed to work? Or check the Mongoose API to see if there's an option to make it asynchronous or non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

mg_wakeup_server_ex wakeup the server thread, the one call mg_poll_server.

From mongoose documentation [mg_wakeup_server_ex](http://cesanta.com/docs/API.shtml) :

> Sends string message to a server. Function func is called for every
>   active connection. String message is passed in struct
>   mg_connection::callback_param. This function is designed to push data
>   to the connected clients, and can be called from any thread. There is
>   a limitation on the length of the message, currently at 8 kilobytes.

As it use socketpair to communicate, it will deadlock if you call it from the server thread. In such a case you should replace with mg_iterate_over_connections.

Your code will becomes something like :

```
static int websocket_data_push(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev)
{
    const char* msg = (const char*)conn->callback_param;
    if ((ev == MG_POLL) && (NULL != conn->uri) && (NULL != msg))
    {
        if (strcmp(conn->uri, "/web") == 0 && conn->is_websocket) 
        {
            mg_websocket_printf(conn, WEBSOCKET_OPCODE_TEXT, msg);
        }
    }
    return MG_FALSE;
}  
void SampleClass::sendEventsToClient(const char* evString)
{
    if(evString != NULL)
    {
        char msg[8*1024];
        snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg),"%lu %s", (unsigned long) time(NULL), evString);
        mg_iterate_over_connections(mgserver, websocket_data_push,(void*)&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connection Pointer is NULL\n");
    }
}
```

If you want to use mg_wakeup_server_ex, you should call it from a thread, for instance created using mg_start_thread.